# Transform splines like a mesh

Tags: modeling, modifiers, transforms, svg

I added wave modifiers to a mesh and want to have the same transformation to a imported svg respectively splines.
I tried to add the same modifiers to the svg but of course this doesn’t do it as it’s no mesh.

This is the mesh:
[image: this is the mesh]

This is the svg hovering above the mesh:
[image: This is the svg above the mesh]

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

In order to deform any object smoothly you need to have enough geometry so that the object can hold any form it is deformed to. So for example a simple cube can have 8 vertices and hold its form:

[image]

However if I wanted to use a wave modifier and maybe animate it I would need thousands of vertices instead of the 8 for the exact same cube, because 8 vertices cannot convey the forms needed:

[image]

The same applies to whatever vector graphics you import.

One way would be to convert the curves to meshes, then take the messy triangulated geometry that would not deform well, extrude it and use it to cut a dense grid plane with boolean modifier. This way you would have some uniform density geometry you can deform:

[image]